# Simplifying a sentence

Tags: meaning, grammar

> The logistics were those of a very large army, which indeed it was,
>   battalions of extras and theatrical performers for the biggest sound
>   set ever conceived.

Could someone simplify this sentence please?

Comment: Hi. I'm afraid we don't do proofreading, or do your language work for you. If  you have a specific question about whether a specific simplification is valid we will be happy to answer a question about it.

Comment: Break it up; that's too much for one sentence. E.g, _The logistics were the logistics of a very large army. And it was indeed a very large army; it had battalions of extras and theatrical performers, all destined for the biggest sound set that was ever conceived._

Answer (score 1):

I would move the topic of the sentence up, and break it up into a separate sentence as well. You bury the lede after a convoluted introduction:

> The sound set was the biggest ever conceived. Its logistics were like those of a very large army, which indeed it was, with battalions of extras and theatrical performers.

Comment: is "with" connected to army? like men with umbrella,so its logistics were like those of theatrical performers and a very large amry with battalions of extras

Comment: battalion is used metaphorically. It refers to a military unit of command of several thousand people (specifics depend on nation/branch of military), here the author is saying there are so many performers, you could chunk them as a battalion